# with java encoded json string fails to decode with php

Tags: java, php, json, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm really struggling with encoding strings with Java and PHP.
I use Java to manage posts in Wordpress. For this I created a GUI in JavaFX and extended the REST-API to create SEO-inserts. The Worpdress-database is encoded with utf8_general_ci.
I send the data as JSON-encoded String via Post to the WP-Api. I use org.JSON. for de-/encoding in Java.
I tried to decode the json-string with php,

> json_decode($request->get_param('data'), true);

but i get following error:

> Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

So i tried to convert it with php

> $s = iconv("Windows-1252", "UTF-8", $s);

It worked but characters like "ä,ö,ü,ß" etc. just appear as Ã¼, Ã,...

Next I tried it to encode it in Java, as described here [Converting Java String From/to utf-8](https://fabioangelini.wordpress.com/2011/08/04/converting-java-string-fromto-utf-8/)

```
private String convertToUTF8(String s) {
    String out = null;
    try {
        out = new String(s.getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1");
    } catch (java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return null;
    }
    return out;
}
```

But with that and without "iconv" it fails again.

What am I doing wrong and how can i solve this?

The server runs with php7.0. I use jdk1.8.0_66 for Java.

Comment: Your `convertToUTF8` doesn't "convert" ***to*** UTF-8 it "converts" ***from*** UTF-8

Comment: @Tom No, it doesn't do even that. It exports string to "UTF-8" representation and than imports it as if it was "ISO-8859-1", therefore it produces some garbage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning an encryption with a `String` object is a common mistake. `String`s are supposed to be an abstraction over such implementation details as encoding. As long as you're only working with `String`s, all you need to know is that they're Unicode. The specific encoding comes into play only when you convert `String` to bytes, which in your case will probably mean in some HTTP client. I don't know what do you use, so I've attached an example for the one from Apache.

```
public void sendMessage(CloseableHttpClient client, String endpointUrl, String jsonString) throws IOException {
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(endpointUrl);
    post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"); // Apache would probably set it for you, but since I'm not 100% sure, I added it here.
    post.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonString, ContentType.create("application/json", Consts.UTF_8))); // here the actual conversion takes place and only here do you need to worry about encoding
    try (CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(post)) {
        // act on response here
    }
}
```

**Remark 1**: This example is just that: an example, meant to illustrate a point. I haven't tested it, and I don't know Apache HTTP client that well, so be careful.

**Remark 2**: It seems that you can use `ContentType APPLICATION_JSON` instead of `ContentType.create("application/json", Consts.UTF_8)` - it uses UTF-8 by default. But in the context of your question this way seems to be clearer.